# Why does increasing features lead to worse neural network performance?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have a regression problem and configured a multi-layered neural network using Keras. The original dataset had 286 features, and using 20 epochs, the NN converged to a MSE loss of ~0.0009. This is using the Adam optimizer.

I then added three more features, and using the same configuration, the NN won't converge. After 1 epoch, it gets stuck at a loss of 0.003, so significantly worse.

After checking that the new features are represented correctly, I have tried the following with no success:

- adjusting number of layers
- adjusting number of neurons in each layer
- including dropout layers
- adjusting the learning rate

Here is my original configuration:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', 
input_dim=training_set.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='mse')
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: what type are the 3 new features? Are the feature values significantly different from the first 286 features? Maybe you need to normalize/standardize the input differently with the newly added features.

Comment: They're numerical features and I scaled them in the same manner as the other numerical features. I'll try log scaling them and seeing if that makes a difference

Comment: a few questions: 1. is it timeseries regression? 2. are the three new features relevant to the thing you are trying to predict? 3. How much training data do you have? High-dimensionality data requires more training data, b/c models will suffer from the curse of dimensionality

Comment: I'm trying to predict how long it will take to drive from one part of a city to  another and the model does include time series. The features I added were related to the fastest route i.e. the shortest distance, fastest travel time and number of 'steps'. I have ~1.5M rows of training data

Comment: Maybe you have too many irrelevant features, you can try to add L1 regularization to do feature selection.